# Data loss during sending via $_SESSION from one script to another

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm trying to send an object full of properties from one PHP to another with:

```
$_SESSION['object'] = $obj;
```

where **$obj** is an object designated with foreach loop:

```
foreach($array_of_objects as $obj) {
    $_SESSION['object'] = $obj;
    // here the second PHP file is invoked as a lightbox with tinybox2
    echo "<article onclick=\"TINY.box.show({url:'tinybox2/popup.php',boxid:'popup'})\">Article Content</article>";
}
```

In second PHP file, I try to print the object passed:

```
print_r($_SESSION['object']);
```

and all the properties that had date in format of Y-m-d (yyyy-mm-dd, eg. 2016-08-31) are just empty, and looks that way:

```
Card Object (
    [number] => 1234
    [order_number] => ABCDE0000012345
    [name] => Test Name
    [date_composed] => 2016-08-31 14:28
    [companys] => My Company \ 100 %
    [selected_company] => My Company
    [selected_company_part] => 100
    [user] => Test User Name
    [status] => test status 123
    [group] => Dummy
    [coordinator] => Test Coordinator Name
    [order_type] => n/a
    [supplier] => Test Supplier
    [task_completion_date] =>
    [confirmed_completion_date] =>
    [department] => Test Department
    [priority] => 2 - medium
    [created_by] => Test Creator Name
    [cost] => 0
    [external_status] => test status 321
)
```

You can clearly see something is wrong with two properties. Their correct values shall be:

> (...) [task_completion_date] => 2016-09-10 [confirmed_completion_date] => 2016-09-05 (...)

For testing, I tried out sending the whole object that array of objects is stored in:

```
$_SESSION['object_with_array'] = $object_with_array;
```

and viewed it in the second PHP, and... the properties that were gone in the first approach, here are intact and working!

> (...) [task_completion_date] => 2016-09-10 [confirmed_completion_date] => 2016-09-05 (...)

Therefore I want to send only one object from the array, not the whole object that contains the array. Also viewing the **$obj** variable and **$_SESSION['object']** in the first PHP does result in viewing dates stored in both object instances (as shared above), so the problem happens during the reading from the session in the second PHP file, not during saving or reading in the first one.

**My question is: what is happening to those dates stored in an object during sending the object via session to the second file and why is it happening only when sending the single object, but not the more abstractive object containing array of less abstractive objects?** How to make the process work properly?

**FYI**
The class the object is built on looks similar to the below:

```
class Card
{
    // PROPERTIES
    public $number;
    public $order_number;
    public $name;
    public $date_composed; // FORMAT: yyyy-mm-dd hours:mins; WORKS IN 2'nd PHP
    public $companys;
    public $selected_company;
    public $selected_company_part;
    public $user;
    public $status;
    public $group;
    public $coordinator;
    public $type;
    public $supplier;
    public $task_completion_date; // THIS DATE DISAPEARS
    public $confirmed_completion_date; // THIS DATE DISAPPEARS
    public $department;
    public $priority;
    public $created_by;
    public $cost;
    public $external_status;

    // METHODS
    // Main public constructor
    public function __construct($data) {
        $column = 0;
        foreach($this as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $data[$column];
            $column++;
        }
    }
```

The array of objects mentioned above is stored in a class similar to below:

```
class Cards
{
    // PROPERTIES
    public $houseOfCards; // $array_of_objects
    // some other properties that ain't important       

    // METHODS
    // Public constructor reading data from CSV files to objects in an array
    public function __construct() {
        $this->houseOfCards = array();      
        // Here the reading from CSV happens to $data in a loop
            $this->houseOfCards[] = new Card($data);
        // file is being closed after it is read whole
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Are the dates in a string format or are they themselves datetime objects?

Comment: Should `$_SESSION['object'] = $obj;` be `$_SESSION['object'][] = $obj;`

Comment: Do you have any PHP Error reportings?

Comment: Instead of `foreach($array_of_objects as $obj) {
    $_SESSION['object'] = $obj;
    // here the second PHP file is invoked as a lightbox with tinybox2
    echo "<article onclick=\"TINY.box.show({url:'tinybox2/popup.php',boxid:'popup'})\">Article Content</article>";
}`

why dont you use
`$_SESSION['object'] = $array_of_objects`

Comment: @nerdlyist, nope, it shouldn't. But you seem to find a mistake in my thinking, and I'll check it out in a sec. Stupid me... :x

Comment: @Martin, it's a string.
Also, I do not have any PHP Errors, though thanks to nerdlyist I found a mistake in my thinking. I didn't want to pass the whole array while I only needed one object from the array (it ain't both very secure nor clean / memory optimized option), but it may be the only option...

Comment: @RyanVincent, could you please expand that case? I suppose it isn't the thing, but is interesting enough to check it out ^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I checked out what could I do wrong, and when I saw it, I literally... nevermind. Therefore, here's the answer.

Never. Ever. Pass. Data. While. Displaying. Stuff.

Otherwise you'll overwrite your data over and over... :x

What happened is that, my last element of array doesn't have **$task_completion_date**. And that last element was the one that my second PHP saw. Why? Because I was sending the object each time the invoking element was *displayed*, not *clicked*.

Though I don't really have an idea how to send properly only one object data to the second script, at the moment I'm sending whole **$array_of_objects** with session before I even start displaying stuff the user can click on. Each clickable element gained the key value sent by *tinybox2* post function. Now I can access data through:

```
$the_object_i_need = $_SESSION['array_of_objects'][$_POST['key']];
```

or to be clearer
    $array = $_SESSION['array_of_objects'];
    $key = $_POST['key'];
    $the_object_i_need = $array[$key];

Only the key value may be visible to the user through the fact it's sent via tinybox2 implementation of POST, and I don't really like it, but for sure this solves my problem and I can access proper object data in the second file.

Thanks for @nerdlyist for inspiration to write this answer and @sumit-badaya for once again suggesting the idea of passing the whole array, which I tried to ommit.

Current PHP1:

```
$_SESSION['array_of_objects'] = $array_of_objects;
foreach($array_of_objects as $key=>$obj) {
    // here the second PHP file is invoked as a lightbox with tinybox2
    echo "<article onclick=\"TINY.box.show({url:'tinybox2/popup.php',post:'key=$key',boxid:'popup'})\">Article Content</article>";
}
```

Current PHP2:

```
$array_of_objects = $_SESSION['array_of_objects'];
$key = $_POST['key'];
$requested_object = $array_of_objects[$key];
// Here the data is printed in a form of nice table
```